# Keep numbers between brackets and remove the rest

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, statistics

I have a column in a data frame which contains statistical numbers like these

| percentage |
| --- |
| 32/40 (80%) |
| 56/60 (93%) |

how to keep only the 80% and 90% and remove the total number, I'm a beginner at pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non regex approach would be to

```
df.col1.str.rsplit('(').str[1].str.rstrip(')'))
```

The logic here is that you split your string than grab the percent values and them, strip the unwonted ")" part of the string. Not the most optimal way but it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["percentage"] = df["percentage"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)')
```

Comment: did that but I got a
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Comment: Sorry...typo, I should have wrapped the entire pattern in a capture group `(...)`